# Can I remove the fresh air supply that is attached next to my furnace?

Tags: hvac, furnace, hot-water

It looks like my gas furnace is already vented but I'm not sure. There are two white pipes from the top of the furnace that are vented outside. The furnace is a Trane XR90. We have cold winter climate in Canada

The gas hot water heater has a black pvc pipe to the outside.

[image: The fresh air supply that is attached next to my furnace]
[image: Gas furnace]
[image: Gas hot water heater]

Comment: Probably not, but it's nearly impossible for anybody to know for sure without actually coming to your house.

Comment: Where is the water heater's air intake?  Is that black pipe concentric?  Or only an exhaust?

Comment: @Tester101 good point maybe I need to get an HVAC guy in.

Comment: @wallyk I'm not sure... I should probably get someone to come look at it.

Comment: @ShawnH:  Maybe look at the other end of the black pipe?

Comment: @wallyk I just looked at the other end of the black pipe. The pipe doesn't have any attachments outside, so maybe it's only an exhaust?
I wonder if all hot water heaters need a fresh air supply hooked up to it?

Comment: The black pipe on the water heater is probably exhaust, not intake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All fuel burning devices need an air supply.  In the case of direct vent appliances, there is an air intake to be plumbed to the outdoors as well as an exhaust pipe.  This assures that the appliance is not drawing air into the house through windows, doors, etc. defeating weatherization and sealing.  The combustion chamber in DV appliances is closed and isolated from the room.  Even a direct vent fireplace is completely enclosed to allow no air to enter from—or exit to—the room.

Direct venting is still largely the exception rather than the rule, though DV is gaining favor with many people who prefer higher energy and cost efficiency, so much new construction is now using DV.

A 1950s gas water heater has an air intake, but it simply draws air from its surroundings.

That water heater does not appear to be direct vent, so a general air supply for it is needed and the "floating beanstalk" air tube is a reasonable way to achieve ventilation—removing it would be "bad".

It occurs to me to try to decrease the chilling effect the intake causes for the room by moving it closer to the water heater, and maybe even "boxing it off" somewhat.  However, if the outdoor air is very cold, like below -30°C/-22°F, and there is a lot of airflow, such an arrangement could damage the plumbing and tank by freezing water in the pipes, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen people put a 5 gallon bucket under that vent. If your house has new windows or has been upgraded ,by which makes your house tighter, you need that vent to breath for the furnace and water Heater.